# Automatically replacing only particular characters in a string

Tags: r, string

To show you my problem. We have a string containing a random system of equations:

```
x0<-"3w+2x+y-3z=-5; 5w+x+2z=31; -2w-x+3y+4z=7; -3x-5y+z=8"
```

Next steps:

```
varnames <- sort(strapply(x0, "[a-z]", simplify = unique))
spl <- strsplit(x0, ";")[[1]]
my_string<-unlist(spl)
my_string<-trimws(my_string)
ss1 <- gsubfn("[a-z]", x ~ (match(x, varnames) == seq_along(varnames))+0, 
spl)
ss2 <- gsub("(\\d)c", "\\1*c", ss1)
ss3 <- sub("=.*", "", ss2)
A <- eval(parse(text = paste("rbind(", paste(ss3, collapse = ","), ")")))
b <- as.numeric(sub(".*=", "", ss2))

z<-matrix(cbind(A,b), nrow=ncol(cbind(A,b)), ncol=nrow(cbind(A,b)), 
byrow=TRUE)
x1<-toString(z)
x1<-stringr::str_replace_all(z1,","," &")
x1
```

The output is:

```
3 & 2 & 1 & -3 & -5 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 31 & -2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 7 & 0 & -3 & -5 & 1 & 8
```

But I want to achieve:

```
3 & 2 & 1 & -3 &|& -5 \\ 5 & 1 & 0 & 2 &|& 31 \\ -2 & -1 & 3 & 4 &|& 7 \\ 0  & -3 & -5 & 1 &|& 8
```

It means how to replace in x1 every fourth (in this example) "&" char (which stands in the x0 string for "=") with "&|&" and every fifth "&" (which stands in the x0 for ";") with "\\" to be able to create in markdown a Latex table, like this:

[image: rmatrix]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your output example is right? Where did the first `-4` go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man that took a lot out of me, lol. Feels like there must be an easier way..

```
library(stringr)
x2 <- str_replace_all(x1, '(-?\\d+\\s&\\s-?\\d+\\s&\\s-?\\d+\\s&\\s)(-?\\d+\\s?)&?\\s?(-?\\d+)\\s?&?\\s?', '\\1\\2&|& \\3 \\\\ ')
x2 <- substr(x2, 1, nchar(x2)-3)
x2
#[1] "3 & 2 & 1 & -3 &|& -5 \\ 5 & 1 & 0 & 2 &|& 31 \\ -2 & -1 & 3 & 4 &|& 7 \\ 0 & -3 & -5 & 1 &|& 8"
```